# facebook log in button error

Tags: android, debugging

I tried to add facebook log in button in my app, even after successful compiling it is getting crashed in emulator.

following is the error report as per logcat, kindly help me to resolve it out.

Thanks

```html
06-12 15:10:39.983  18518-18518/? I/art﹕ Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
06-12 15:10:41.167  18518-18528/com.example.prashant.nuhani_go W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 361.261ms
06-12 15:10:41.353  18518-18518/com.example.prashant.nuhani_go D/Key Hash:-﹕ gMvqxy6TyRo8c0U4xwDiHZhq8gY=
06-12 15:10:41.363  18518-18543/com.example.prashant.nuhani_go D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
06-12 15:10:41.367  18518-18518/com.example.prashant.nuhani_go D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb42d68e0, tid 18518
06-12 15:10:41.377  18518-18518/com.example.prashant.nuhani_go D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
06-12 15:10:41.471  18518-18543/com.example.prashant.nuhani_go D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
06-12 15:10:41.472  18518-18543/com.example.prashant.nuhani_go D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
06-12 15:10:41.484  18518-18543/com.example.prashant.nuhani_go D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
06-12 15:10:41.502  18518-18543/com.example.prashant.nuhani_go D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaf0395c0, tid 18543
06-12 15:10:41.530  18518-18543/com.example.prashant.nuhani_go I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
06-12 15:10:41.709  18518-18543/com.example.prashant.nuhani_go D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
06-12 15:10:41.760  18518-18543/com.example.prashant.nuhani_go W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-12 15:10:41.760  18518-18543/com.example.prashant.nuhani_go W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xaf0358a0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
06-12 15:10:41.970  18518-18518/com.example.prashant.nuhani_go I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-12 15:10:41.988  18518-18553/com.example.prashant.nuhani_go E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
    Process: com.example.prashant.nuhani_go, PID: 18518
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Object.hashCode()' on a null object reference
            at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:746)
            at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.containsKey(ConcurrentHashMap.java:774)
            at com.facebook.internal.Utility.queryAppSettings(Utility.java:825)
            at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$1.run(LoginButton.java:486)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
06-12 15:10:43.514  18518-18518/com.example.prashant.nuhani_go I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 92 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

and my activity.java code snippet is as follows

```html
package com.example.prashant.nuhani_go;

import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import android.content.pm.Signature;

import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;


public class learningActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_learning);
        getUserInfo();
    }

    public void getUserInfo() {

        try{
        PackageInfo info= getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for(Signature signature:info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("Key Hash:- ", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }


        }
        catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {}
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e){}



    }


}
```

Comment: have you added hascode in Facebook developer page, at your project page.?

Comment: PackageInfo info= getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for(Signature signature:info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("Key Hash:- ", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }


        }
        catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {}
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e){}

Comment: i hve added this in my main activity.

Comment: Oho then its problem with emulator... try in phone(real device).. it will fix your error.

Comment: again..same problem. crashing !

Comment: Hey, got the solution

i was using---> android:name="com.facebook.sdk.appId"

instead of--> android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" in my mainifest file to include hash id.